# facebook wall application?

Tags: facebook

i am about to start developing for facebook. before i begin i wanted to know abt this little thing. is it possible to make an app that is placed on top of the user's wall above the status message box?

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeking for the prominent placing - the answer is no

but you can integrate an app into the wall via the publisher. 
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Publisher

The areas you can fully integrate your app is the left bar and the tabs